# $ is undefined on 1 page although fine from included file on all other pages

Tags: jquery

I have an error that I cannot work out.

My site has an included head.php file which loads in 1) Jquery 2) Jquery Libraries then the body html etc so in that respect everything is loading in order.

on one page though I get a $ is undefined in the javascript console pointing to the same `$(document).ready(function(){`

It only does it on this one page. All the pages are included through index.php and called from a database as an include in the  the head is always loaded first.

Now the interesting thing is when I inspect in firebug everything is loading in ok... The Jquery, the libraries and my call for document ready. ALSO the functionality of JQUERY is still working (like for the tabs and accordions) its just that I'm getting this error pop up and its then failing to initilise the PHPHTMLEDIT (Html Editor)

So my code looks like this - index.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once('connections/application.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <?php include_once('main_head.php'); ?>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- website container -->
    <div id="container" >

        <?php include_once('main_banner.php'); ?>
        <?php include_once('main_columns.php'); ?>
        <?php include_once('main_footer.php'); ?>

    </div>
    <!-- end website container -->

</body>
</html>
<?php mssql_close($conn); ?>
```

main_head.php

```
<!-- title of the page -->
<title>page title</title>


<!-- Jquery plugins -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="scripts/jquery.smartTab.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="scripts/jquery.ui.accordion.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="scripts/floatbox.js"></script>



<link href="styles/smart_tabs/smart_tab.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- Website Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="scripts/onload.js"></script>
```

The error is occuring in onload.js - Jquery is loaded first. But I am getting the error as if jquery were not loaded.

Any help much appreciated. I checked the folder permissions and are all ok. I'm a bit baffled to why its throwing this error on one page in particular and jquery IS still working...

Thanks

Andi

Added @ 10.56 **

Sorry this is the onload.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#creation_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    $('#operations_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    $('#publish_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    $('#tabs').smartTab({selected: 0,autoProgress: false,stopOnFocus:true,transitionEffect:'SlideUp'});

});
```

Comment: Two things, could you post the code in `onload.js` which is causing the error, and also check the HTML source in the browser to make sure that jQuery is being included as you assume it is.

Comment: Log the value of `$` to the console just before the line which throws the error.

Comment: This is the code in onload.js     $(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('#creation_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
 $('#operations_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
 $('#publish_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
 $('#tabs').smartTab({selected: 0,autoProgress:     false,stopOnFocus:true,transitionEffect:'SlideUp'});
       
});

Comment: Sorry I'll put it down below where it is easier to read

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Posted the Jquery see above. And yes in Firebug the Jquery is being loaded in the head. And all the other javascript files after that. Also the JQUERY is still working as my datepickers are working and my tabs. Its just the window is throwing an error and the PHPHTML editor is not working. I've taken the PHPHTML editor out and it's still throwing the same error so it's not the PHPHTMLEDITOR.

Comment: I also put an alert in the $(document).ready(function({ and its calling the alert. So it is working but I'm still getting the error for that line.

Comment: I've also made sure the MIME type has .js extension and it's cleared up the PHPHTMLEDITOR error but I still get this wierd $ error. Bambuzzled :o?

Comment: I would try removing the plugins one by one to see if any of them are introducing the error somehow.

Comment: @GraemeHill I've just tried that so that all that was being pulled in was jquery. It still throws the error. It doesn't on any other templated page so its wierd to get that error and jquery functionality still work.

Answer (score 0):

There maybe a conflict with some other library.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Can you try this:

```
 $.noConflict();
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
   $('#creation_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
   $('#operations_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
   $('#publish_date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
   $('#tabs').smartTab({selected: 0,autoProgress: false,stopOnFocus:true,transitionEffect:'SlideUp'});

  });
```

Comment: I tried that didn't work. :o( Not sure what to try next. I did try taking out all the other libraries still got the weird error but Jquery still works. I think the server has issues as well so maybe its not processing properly.

Comment: Have you loaded all the libraries that include datepicker and smartTab?  Do you have a public link to review?

Comment: Yes in the main_head.php... The error does not appear on any other page but I'm also using uploadify. I took out the uploadify and its still throwing the error.